# Locking the mouse cursor to an Xbox 360 controller, on OS X

Tags: controllers, macos

Is there any way to lock the mouse cursor to an analog stick, on a regular Xbox 360 controller, in OS X?

Basically, I want the mouse cursor to move with the analog, but also conform to its constraints. That is, when I release the analog stick and the analog resets to the center position, I would prefer the cursor to **also** move back to the center of the screen.

I've tried out all sorts of things on ControllerMate, but maybe I'm missing something. This video shows another user using the same sort of feature I am trying to access.

Comment: For future reference, any question asking if software exists is classified as a recommendation request, for the purposes of Arqade. Instead, ask yourself 'what do I want it to do', and just ask us if there is a way to complete your actual objective.

A good answer will point you in the direction of the software, anyway, if it does exist. Furthermore, if there is any way to complete the same function **without** software, your still leaving your question open to the other solutions.

Comment: I've made the suitable changes to combat the close voting, but you should get the jist of it, so if I have mis-interpretted what your trying to do, feel free to change it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use custom software like [Enjoy2](https://github.com/fyhuang/enjoy2/blob/master/README.md). Unfortunately, I don't have a Mac, so I can't test it myself, but, based on the code and the documentation, it is possible to configure a mapping where your analog stick's offset will translate to the mouse cursor's location on the string. To add further complications, Enjoy2 appears to have been abandoned.

Alternatively, [USB Overdrive](http://www.usboverdrive.com/USBOverdrive/Information.html) is actively maintained, but not open source, so I have even less of an idea how to go about configuring it properly.

Comment: @Timelord64 It requires a bit of extra work to set it up that way, but it is possible.

Comment: What I mean to say, even in the original version that almost got closed, it seemed pretty obvious that the user was asking for something that would reset the cursor with the analog. It might be worth directly addressing how you would go about it

Comment: @Timelord64 I'll include the details of how to set it up like that once I get a chance to sit down at a computer and write it up. Mobile is not conducive for writing detailed answers.